# omnet++ delete a module element

Tags: omnet++

I need to delete sensor node if its energy level is less than 0.Every sensor nodes has inout gate.Every sensor node is also connected to the LCN.LCN has inout gate.
 I wrote this code to delete the module.

```
if(totPower<0){
       deleteModule();
       callFinish();
    }
```

it works but If another request is came to this lcn to sensing data, Lcn assume this deleted sensor module is still connected to it and throws connection error.How can I solve this problem?By the way I am using just Omnet++, not inet,castalia etc.

```
<!> Error in module (LCN) Network.lcn[7] (id=254) at event #188, t=1200: send()/sendDelayed(): gate `lcnSN$o[11]' not connected.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should change declaration of connection in your network `NED` into:

```
connections allowunconnected:
```

It allows gate to be left unconnected.

Secondly, `callFinish()` should be involve **before** `deleteModule()`. 

Moreover, you have to check whether a gate is connected before sending through it. Sample code:

```
    // i - is an index of gate lcnSN you want to send
    cGate *outGate = gate("lcnSN$o", i);
    if (outGate->isConnected()) {
        send(msg, "lcnSN$o", i);
    }
```

The suffix `$o` means an output part of the gate.